# Rounding of /ɪ/ ending up with an /ʏ/ sound?

Tags: phonetics

I just watched the Italy-Holland game of the women's World Cup on ARD.  The commentator, Stephanie Baczyk from Hannover, said *Viertelfinale* with what to my ears sounded like /ʏ/ so that it was more like /'fʏrtəlfina:lə/.  Did I just mishear or is there a possible rounding of /ɪ/ in certain environments or with some speakers?

Comment: Your ears are *in Ordnung*. That's indeed one of the common realizations of *Viertel*. It's an exception, though. No one pronounces e.g. *Bier* that way.

Comment: @Janka, it’s not really an exception, the i in Viertel is shorter than in Bier.

Answer (score 3):

Your ears are ok. There are some regions in Germany where people speak [ʏ] (»ü«) where they should speak [ɪ] (»i«). In this regions words like *»Tisch«* or *»Fisch«* are spoken like *»Tüsch«* or *»Füsch«*, and so also *»Viertel«* becomes *»Fürtel«*.

As far as I can say, this only happens to the darker [ɪ]-sound like in the given examples, but not to the brighter [i]-sound that you most often find as a long vowel. ([ɪ] is always short, even in *»Viertel«*, although it's spelling indicates a long vowel.) If my hypothesis is true, then *»Miete«* [ˈmiːtə] will be left unchanged, while *»Mitte«* [ˈmɪtə] should sound like *»Mütte«* [ˈmʏtə].

I do not live in such an area, so its hard for me to tell if this is true or not, but i'm shure, there will be some comments about this hypothesis.

---

<sup>Just to make it clear: The first vowel in the word *»vier«* is long: [fiːɐ̯]. But the vowel in *»Viertel«* is short: [ˈfɪʁtl̩]. (Funny enough, *»vier«* has two spoken vowels ([i] and [ɐ​]) while *»Viertel«* contains only one spoken vowel ([ɪ]).</sup>

Comment: I think the consonant in front of the i matters, too.

Comment: Good answer, but you are wrong about "Mitte". It depends on the sound after the i.